# Iterating through a string using For loop

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to iterate through the characters of string using for loop however I get the following error

```
let str = "Hello"
for var=0 to (String.length str -1) do
  let temp = String.get str var
done;;

Error : Syntax error
```

I tried this code here

```
let str = "Hello";;
for i = 0 to (String.length str -1) do
    Printf.printf "%s" String.get str i
done;;
```

and this is the error i get

```
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b -> 'c)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type unit
```

Comment: its a syntax error yes, there's no in following that temp. What is the value in the loop?

Comment: What do u mean there is no in after the temp variable ?

Comment: let temp = String.get str var in

Comment: where did you get the keyword `in` from . The statement `let temp = String.get str var` does not have the keyword `in` in it

Comment: 1) It's not really a statement, its an expression. 2) This is a let binding, you need an in. Look at basic tutorials, https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html#Forloopsandwhileloops

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am not sure what the in keyword does. I am trying to google on it but cant really understand it

Comment: Its saying I want this value to be valid in all expressions below me.

Comment: I am going to open another question up for that

Comment: Its a very basic OCaml semantic question, not really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Looks like I need to understand what the in keyword does

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work

```
#let s = "Hello";;
s : string = "Hello"
#for i = 0 to string_length s - 1 do
    print_char s.[i]; print_string " "
  done;;
o k - : unit = ()
```